# Set 2D array elements based on 2D index array

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, indexing, element

In Python, say you have a 2D array of zeros of shape (N,4,4):

```
z = array([[[0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0.]],

   [[0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0.]]])
```

and you have a 2D array of indices:

```
i = array([[1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 0]])
```

and some valued 2D array:

```
v = array([[ 2.,  4., 10.,  7.],
   [10.,  9.,  9.,  2.],
   [ 3.,  8.,  8.,  8.],
   [ 8.,  6., 10.,  1.]])
```

Is there a way to fill the elements of `z` with the values of `v` but in the slices denoted by `i`, without using loops?

Note: Is there a way to do this in a scalable fashion such that if you had an N channel array `z`, where N>>1, you would not need to directly index `z[i]` when filling it with values from `v`?

For clarity, the resulting `z` array would look like the following:

```
z = array([[[0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 9., 9., 2.],
    [3., 8., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 1.]],

   [[2., 4., 10., 7.],
    [10., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 8., 8.],
    [8, 6., 10., 0.]]])
```

Obviously, using something like:

```
z = v[i,:,:]
```

would never work but maybe there's a way to use `rows, cols` to do this?

Many thanks in advance!

---

Edit:

For clarity here is a similar example but for a 3D `z` as requested in the comments:

```
z = array([[[0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0.]]])


i = array([[2, 1, 2, 1],
       [1, 1, 2, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 1]])


v = array([[5., 5., 0., 4.],
       [4., 6., 8., 3.],
       [4., 0., 4., 8.],
       [7., 6., 5., 7.]])
```

`z` would become:

```
z = array([[[0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 6., 5., 0.]],

       [[0., 5., 0., 4.],
        [4., 6., 0., 3.],
        [4., 0., 4., 8.],
        [7., 0., 0., 7.]],

       [[5., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 8., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0.]]])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use masks and multiply:

```
from numpy import array
z = array([[[0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0.]],

   [[0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0.]]])
i = array([[1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 0]])
v = array([[ 2.,  4., 10.,  7.],
   [10.,  9.,  9.,  2.],
   [ 3.,  8.,  8.,  8.],
   [ 8.,  6., 10.,  1.]])
z[0] = ~i.astype(bool)*v
z[1] = i.astype(bool)*v
```

Output:

```
z = 
array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  9.,  9.,  2.],
        [ 3.,  8.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]],

       [[ 2.,  4., 10.,  7.],
        [10.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  8.,  8.],
        [ 8.,  6., 10.,  0.]]])
```

For more general case:

```
for ax in np.unique(i):
    mask = i == ax
    z[ax] = mask*v
print(z)
```

Output:

```
[[[0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 6. 5. 0.]]

 [[0. 5. 0. 4.]
  [4. 6. 0. 3.]
  [4. 0. 4. 8.]
  [7. 0. 0. 7.]]

 [[5. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 8. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0.]]]
```

Note: Here I assumed the values in `i` are same as there are channels in `z`. If different, instead of np.unique, you can try:

```
for i_val,ax in zip(np.unique(i),range(z.shape[0]))::
    mask = i == i_val
    z[ax] = mask*v
```

**EDIT**

A one-liner would be:

```
>>> z = np.array([*map(i.__eq__,np.unique(i))])*np.array([v]*z.shape[0])
>>> z
array([[[0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 6., 5., 0.]],

       [[0., 5., 0., 4.],
        [4., 6., 0., 3.],
        [4., 0., 4., 8.],
        [7., 0., 0., 7.]],

       [[5., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 8., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0.]]])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately this wouldn't be scalable for high dimensional versions of `z` with many many channels. That's my fault for not being clear enough in he question though so I've updated the text accordingly.

Comment: Could you provide an example for what you want for `z` with 3 channels?

Comment: Thanks! I tried working that through and it all looks good :D

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: On an extra note, is there an easy way to extend this problem to work with 4D arrays, such as one with shape (5,3,4,4), so that the above solution is carried out on each 2D array (i,3,4,4)? I can add an extension to the question or make a new post if that helps? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the 4D array is `X` then, `for k in range(X.shape[0]):X[k] = np.array([*map(i.__eq__,np.unique(i))])*np.array([v]*X[k].shape[0])`

Comment: Many thanks again! Lastly, is there a way to make this work if the indices don't span the entire channel range? For example, in the problems listed above if the index array was `i = np.zeros(4,4)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Possible using `numpy.where`:

```
z[0] = np.where(i, z[0], v)
z[1] = np.where(1 - i, z[1], v)
```

Output:

```
array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  9.,  9.,  2.],
        [ 3.,  8.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]],

       [[ 2.,  4., 10.,  7.],
        [10.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  8.,  8.],
        [ 8.,  6., 10.,  0.]]])
```

And after your update, if `i` hold the indices of `z` to be changed (and opposite from the 0's and 1's in your example), it can be scaled easily to:

```
for N in range(z.shape[0]):    
    z[N] = np.where(i == N, v, z[N])
```

Or if you really want to avoid loops alltogheter:

```
z = np.where(i == (np.where(np.ones(len(z.reshape(-1))) == 1)[0] // (z.shape[1] * z.shape[2])).reshape(z.shape), v, z)
```

Ouput:

```
array([[[0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 6., 5., 0.]],

   [[0., 5., 0., 4.],
    [4., 6., 0., 3.],
    [4., 0., 4., 8.],
    [7., 0., 0., 7.]],

   [[5., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 8., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0.]]])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately this wouldn't be scalable for high dimensional versions of `z` with many many channels as in the true problem I won't be able to index `z[i]` if there were say hundreds of channels. That's my fault for not being clear enough in he question though so I've updated the text accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Something more complicated without numpy:

```
r = list(zip(i,v))
z[0] = [[l2[i] if l1[i]==0 else 0 for i in range(4)] for l1, l2 in r ]
z[1] = [[l2[i] if l1[i]==1 else 0 for i in range(4)] for l1, l2 in r ]
```

Comment: Thanks, this works but with loops unfortunately.. so not the ideal case but if it can't be done without loops then it's currently the best option.

Comment: @user8188120 it has a nested-loop for **each** of the z[0], z[1]... etc. It is defenitally **not** better than `numpy` solutions who don't have a single loop for each of the z[0], z[1]... etc.